# How to print Image with CPCL command (CG)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, printing

I'm working with a printer that uses CPCL code.
I tried to print Vietnamese text using UTF-8 code, but it seems that the printer or the code does not support Vietnamese printing.

```
String strCommand = '\n! 0 50 20 100 1\r\nENCODING UTF-8\r\nTEXT 01 7 0 0 Xin Chào Việt Nam \r\nPRINT\r\n';
```

Another option I'm thinking is to render the text as an image, and then print it as a CG image. However, things don't seem as simple as I thought. I spent a few days researching how to print using CG commands. But I still can't print.

Below is the code I used but it doesn't work.
The code consists of 2 parts:

- the native part is used to connect the socket to the printer and send it to the printer (only transmits data)
- flutter code: used to process data, convert text, barcode, and image data into List format.

Flutter code:

```
 Future<void> handelCreateImage()async{
    // String text = '\n! 0 100 20 406 1\r\nUTF-8 TEXT 7 03 30 40 Xin Chào Việt Nam\r\nPRINT\r\n';
    String str = 'Xin Chào Việt Nam';
    
    var builder = ParagraphBuilder(ParagraphStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.normal));
    builder.addText(str);
    Paragraph paragraph = builder.build();
    paragraph.layout(const ParagraphConstraints(width: 100));

    final recorder = PictureRecorder();
    var newCanvas = Canvas(recorder);
    newCanvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, Offset.zero);


    final picture = recorder.endRecording();
    var res = await picture.toImage(100, 100);
    

    String headerCommand = "CG ${res.width} ${res.height} 0 0";

    List<int> data = [];
    
    data.addAll(utf8.encode(headerCommand));
    var imageData =(await res.toByteData())!.buffer.asUint8List().toList();
    data.addAll(imageData);

    // send data to code native
    PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(data);
  }
```

/// Native code (Kotlin) to send data to printer.  (from PrintBluetoothThermalPlugin)

```kotlin
if (call.method == "writebytes") {
            var lista: List<Int> = call.arguments as List<Int>
            var bytes: ByteArray = "\n".toByteArray()

            lista.forEach {
                bytes += it.toByte()
                //Log.d(TAG, "foreah: ${it}")
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream?.run {
                        write(bytes)
                        result.success(true)
                        //Log.d(TAG, "result print: ${bytes}")
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    result.success(false)
                    outputStream = null
                    //mensajeToast("Dispositivo fue desconectado, reconecte")
                    Log.d(TAG, "error state print: ${e.message}")
                    /*var ex:String = e.message.toString()
                    if(ex=="Broken pipe"){
                      Log.d(TAG, "Dispositivo fue desconectado reconecte: ")
                      mensajeToast("Dispositivo fue desconectado, reconecte")
                    }*/
                }
            } else {
                result.success(false)
            }
        }
```

If you have any other ideas to handle, let me know.

===============================================================

[Update]
After consulting @lilvagg  answer, I gradually understood the reason. However, it still hasn't achieved the results I wanted.
First, I tried it with the CG command, the results of which were achieved as follows.
[image: Image when printed with CG command]
Then I replaced it with the EG Command, which printed the image as follows
[image: Image when printed with EG command]
The image was distorted, its width was longer, its height was shorter, and the image was doublicated.
I checked the image data in Uint8List format (Before converting to Binary format) and displayed it on the mobile screen, the resulting image is still the correct size.
[image: Image when view mobile screen]

I'm guessing that either the algorithm converted to hexa data that the machine understood, or the print command caused the image to distort when printed.

References
[document](https://www.barcodedatalink.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/CPCL_Programming_Manual_from_Barcode_Datalink.pdf)

How to print the correct size?

Flutter code update

```
Future<void> handelCreateImage()async{
String str = 'Xin Chào Việt Nam';
 var builder = ParagraphBuilder(ParagraphStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,fontSize: 10, height: 20));
 builder.addText(str);

 final TextStyle style = TextStyle(
   color: Colors.black,
   backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
   decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.dotted,
   decorationColor: Colors.green,
   decorationThickness: 0.25,
   height: 2
   // TODO Add more for testing ;)
 );

 final ui.ParagraphBuilder paragraphBuilder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(
     ui.ParagraphStyle(
       fontSize:   style.fontSize,
       fontFamily: style.fontFamily,
       fontStyle:  style.fontStyle,
       fontWeight: style.fontWeight,
       height: style.height,
       textAlign: TextAlign.start,
     )
 )
   ..pushStyle(style.getTextStyle())
   ..addText(str);

 Paragraph paragraph =  paragraphBuilder.build()
   ..layout(ui.ParagraphConstraints(width: 100));


 final recorder = PictureRecorder();
 var newCanvas = Canvas(recorder);

 newCanvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, Offset.zero);

 final picture = recorder.endRecording();
 ui.Image image = await picture.toImage(100, 100);

 ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
 // ByteData byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/mylogo.jpg');
 Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

 // return pngBytes;

 img.Image? bitmap = img.decodeImage(pngBytes);

 List<String> data = [];
 
 for (int y = 0; y < bitmap!.height; y++) {
   for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.width; x++) {
     img.Pixel pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
     data.add(pixel.r > 128 ? "F" : "0");
   }
 }

 String text =data.fold('', (previousValue, element) => 
 previousValue + element);
 String tmp = """! 0 203 203 100 1\nEG 100 100 0 0 $text\nPRINT""";
 PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(tmp]);
}
```

Navive code:

```
if (call.method == "writebytes") {
            var lista: String = call.arguments as String
            var bytes: ByteArray = "".toByteArray()

            bytes += lista.toByteArray()
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream?.run {
                        write(bytes)
                        result.success(true)
                        //Log.d(TAG, "result print: ${bytes}")
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    result.success(false)
                    outputStream = null
                    //mensajeToast("Dispositivo fue desconectado, reconecte")
                    Log.d(TAG, "error state print: ${e.message}")
                    /*var ex:String = e.message.toString()
                    if(ex=="Broken pipe"){
                      Log.d(TAG, "Dispositivo fue desconectado reconecte: ")
                      mensajeToast("Dispositivo fue desconectado, reconecte")
                    }*/
                }
            } else {
                result.success(false)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Future<void> handleCreateImage() async {
  String str = 'Xin Chào Việt Nam';

  var builder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(ui.ParagraphStyle(fontStyle: ui.FontStyle.normal));
  builder.addText(str);
  ui.Paragraph paragraph = builder.build();
  paragraph.layout(const ui.ParagraphConstraints(width: 100));

  final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  var newCanvas = ui.Canvas(recorder);
  newCanvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, ui.Offset.zero);

  final picture = recorder.endRecording();
  ui.Image image = await picture.toImage(100, 100);

  ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

  img.Image? bitmap = img.decodeImage(pngBytes);

  List<int> data = [];
  for (int y = 0; y < bitmap!.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.width; x++) {
      int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
      data.add(img.getRed(pixel) > 128 ? 0 : 1);
    }
  }

  String headerCommand = "CG ${bitmap.width} ${bitmap.height} 0 0 ";
  List<int> command = [];
  command.addAll(utf8.encode(headerCommand));
  command.addAll(data);

  PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(command);
}
```

This code is specifically designed to work with printers that require binary data for images, where white is represented by 0 and black is represented by 1. While you may need to modify the conversion process from pixel color to binary data to meet the specific requirements of your printer, rest assured that this code will work as expected with printers that adhere to the aforementioned specifications.

Comment: Thank you @lilvagg . I tried your way, it seems you guessed in the right direction. However, the printed image does not match the rendered image. I have updated the code in the question. Hope to receive more help from you. I would like to award 50 reputation points for your efforts to help the community